# How do I Utilize Regex Pattern Matching to Validate Input (digit(0-2) [space] [digit(0-2)])?

Tags: regex, validation

First of all, thanks for taking the time to read through this.  I am trying to implement input validation in a program, but I am not certain how to do it.  I am aiming for input as such:

***digit between 0 and 2 + whitespace + digit between 0 and 2***

After much debating, I came to the conclusion that the pattern matcher would be the best method, but I am open to any better suggestions.  Thanks again.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what language are you using? This sounds like Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex .

[0-2]+(\s)+[0-2]+

+ is here for 1 or more

* is for 0 or more

Comment: Don't use class for one char

Answer (score 0):

This is simple:

- digit between 0 and 2 `[0-2]`
- whitespace `\s`
- digit between 0 and 2 `[0-2]`

Comment: Don't forget to wrap it in `^…$`

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-2]\s[0-2]
```

This is regex for you

Here are some links  for regex testing

**[Link1](http://regexpal.com/)**

**[Link2](http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html)**